# Tab realignment needs refresh in salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app, tab

I have changed settings of a tab for different profiles and  have also changed the location of the tab (to appear at the last). I noticed that these changes do not reflect in Salesforce1 if I close / open the app again.

I will have to log out and log in for these changes to appear. The problem is here lot of users need to log out and log in back to pick up the changes. 
Is there a way to circumvent this? as it's difficult for all users to log out and log back in.

I would expect that the changes get picked if we close the app and launch it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user clears his/her cache on their device, the changes should appear. That's the real issue that's preventing the changes from being "pushed" to their Salesforce1 compatible device.